# Select all the child inside a div using :not or other workaround through CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have html something like this:

```css
.wrapper_1 {
  color: red;
}

.container *:not(.wrapper_1) {
  color: blue;
}

.wrapper_2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>This is the test content 1 .</span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper_1">
        This is the test content 2
        <br>
        <span>This is the test content 3</span>
      </div>
      <span class="wrapper_2">This is the test content 4.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to apply or replace container CSS for all the children except the `div` having class `wrapper_1`(all the nested children). As I know I can do something like this: `.container *:not(.wrapper_1)` but it's not ignoring all the children inside `.wrapper` class, Is there any other workaround?

Comment: you have issue with space `.container *:not (.wrapper_1)  {` after not make space will resolve your issue

Comment: The issue is right now the first content inside wrapper_1 should have the color: red, but what I want is all the elements inside wrapper_1 should have the color red.

Comment: Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmv7j46a/

Comment: Use `!important` to make sure it have overwrite power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can learn here how to use `:not` `CSS` selector here [:not css trick](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

```css
.wrapper_1 {
  color: red;
}
.container *:not(.wrapper_1,.wrapper_1 > *){
  color: blue;
}
.wrapper_2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <span>This is the test content 1 .<span>
         </div>
         <div class="wrapper_1">
              This is the test content 2
            <br>
            <span>This is the test content 3</span>
         </div>
         <span class="wrapper_2">This is the test content 4.</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this style:

```
<style>
  .wrapper_1 {
    color: red;
  }
  .container *:not(.wrapper_1.*)  {
               color: blue;
  }
  .wrapper_2{
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: In this case, wrapper_2 also change it to green. I want to have the container color:blue should apply for all the elements except wrapper_1 and its children.